# OneToMany/ManyToOne Bidirectional not working

Tags: symfony, doctrine

Hi everyone and thanks for help,

I'm currently dealing with a problem while I want to make an OneToMany/ManyToOne Bidirectional Relationship with Doctrine2 (& Symfony2.5.6).

Here are my two classes : Voiture , and Voiture modeles

```
namespace Esprit\ParcBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

 /**
* @ORM\Entity
*/
class Voiture
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
private $serie;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="date")
 */
private $dateM;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
private $marque;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ModeleVoiture")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $id_m;
```

and :

```
 <?php

 namespace Esprit\ParcBundle\Entity;

 use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class ModeleVoiture
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;

/**
 *@ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
private $libelle;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
private $pays;
```

when i want to phpmyadmin to check if the foreign key relationis added or no, i can't find it 
thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove `@ORM\Column(type="integer")` from `private $id_m;`